# Strategy to handle expiry of refresh token

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, authentication, jwt

I am making a react application and using JWT for authentication.
As soon as a user logs in I issue a access token and set a http only cookie named jwt and value is refresh token. As per some articles I have read online it is suggested that access token have a short validity and refresh token have a long validity, so I set validity of access token to be 1 day and refresh token to be 25 days, (numbers are not very relevant). Now as soon as refresh token expires The user is automatically logged out.

Now the app I am developing is a data entry dashboard and I do not want the user to suddenly logout after entering a lot of data even if that happens once a month, so I want to know the industry standard to manage this kind of situation

Comment: refresh the token when the user navigates to the form page it is so easy so if the token expires the user can log in again otherwise token will update for 1 day from the time he navigates to the form.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to update refresh token without login-password pair:

1. When a refresh token expires a client have to get a new token pair (access, refresh tokens).
2. The client sends its access AND refresh tokens and receives a new pair (just like when authenticating with username:password).
3. You should track expiry of refresh tokens to prevent their reuse.

It is as safe as your flow because when a client gets logged out it understands that someone else already used its refresh token once. So it has to authenticate using username:password and invalidate the last refresh token.

[I found an article explaining this flow](https://www.loginradius.com/blog/start-with-identity/refresh-tokens-jwt-interaction/#best-practices-to-secure-refresh-tokens)